# No adapter attached to viewpager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I have been trying to implement a viewpager2 in kotlin but i cannot figure out why am i getting an error saying no adapter attached to recycle view
here is my MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        binding.viewpager2.adapter = Viewpager2Adapter(this)
        TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout , binding.viewpager2){
                tab, position ->
            tab.text = "OBJECT ${(position + 1)}"
        }.attach()
    }

}
```

Below is viewpager2Adapter.kt ::

```
class Viewpager2Adapter(fa : FragmentActivity): FragmentStateAdapter(fa)  {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 3

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment= Fragment2()

}
```

This is my fragment2.kt::

```
class Fragment2 : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false)
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me by figuring out what is it that I am doing wrong.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you did not use view binding properly in your MainActivity.
In setContentView you should have binding.root instead of R.layout.activity_main

Here is the code for onCreate function in MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    viewpager2Adapter = Viewpager2Adapter(this)
    viewPager2 = binding.viewpager2
    tabLayout = binding.tabLayout
    viewPager2.adapter = viewpager2Adapter


    TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2){
            tab, position ->
        tab.text = "OBJECT ${(position + 1)}"
    }.attach()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are mixing 2 approaches of inflating activity's view, so the view is then not properly inflated. To fix your issue, replace:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

with

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

And your code should work. The above is the regular approach to apply when you implement databindings. If you would not use databinding, the code would look like follow:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
val viewpager2 = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id. viewpager2)
val tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabLayout)
viewpager2.adapter = Viewpager2Adapter(this)
TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout , viewpager2){
    tab, position ->
    tab.text = "OBJECT ${(position + 1)}"
}.attach()
```

Your app would work with the above code even if you keep the databinding, but of course, using databinding and accessing views through the `binding` instance is much more comfortable compared to `findViewById`.